# How to block an app for 512 mb ram devices?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Sorry for this easy question but I can not find anything within appmanifest or submission form on dev.windows.com.
Where I can set a min Ram of 1 GB for my app?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`ID_REQ_MEMORY_300`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx):

> For Windows Phone 8, indicates that the app requires more than 180 MB of memory and is not suited for a lower-memory device.

180 MB is the most that can be used on devices with < 1 GB, so this is effectively limiting to devices with 1 GB RAM or above.

Comment: Sometimes you can't install apps you see within the store and there is a message "Not availble for your device" or something like that... is it not for this case... I mean whats about games that just can not run on that low RAM?

Comment: here is it I guess https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f9c1b85a-6cd2-4821-9dcb-d05ea5dff1ef/how-to-limit-application-for-special-phones-on-the-store?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: This one should work for WP 8.1 http://sertacozercan.com/2014/12/how-to-opt-out-of-low-memory-devices-on-windows-phone-8-1/

Comment: Doh; not sure how I missed that on the same page - I thought I'd searched for "memory" and gone through them all! Updated my answer with this to avoid misleading.